# Convert a std::vector array in a bi-dimensional C array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

On a project I'm working on, I need some dynamic allocation due to the size of the used data not been known in advance. std::vector seems perfect for this use case. However, due to the software environnement, I can not use "modern" C++ in the headers. I would like to convert this vectors array to be used in fuction with compliant headers.

Quick example:

```cpp
    void func(int tab[][]/*Vector can not be used here*/){/*Do things*/}
    
    int main(){
        std::vector<int> vecTab[6/*Fixed, prior known, dimension*/];
        
        //Adding a random number of values in each vector (equal number in each one)
        //Transformation of vecTab
    
        func(vecTabMod);

        return 1;
    }
```

There is a lot of similar questions on this site, none of them really adressing bi-dimensionnal arrays.

**Bonus point:** no reallocation, access through pointers

Comment: You can use std::vector::data to get a pointer to the internal array. You have `int tab[][]` as the interface though. Does it need to be? Otherwise you can do exactly as the example for the above mentioned method: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data

Comment: I wouldn't call `std::vector` "modern C++", I'd call it "C++". It sounds like these headers are to be consumed by a C compiler too?

Comment: Not a C compiler, however one with overly strict (and dated) rules. Hopefully it doesn't compile my sources, it only uses the header for link edition

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to copy the data pointers into a separate array so that the type and layout matches what the funciton expects. This can be done without heap allocation since the size of this array is fixed.

```cpp
int* vecTabMod[6];
std::transform(std::begin(vecTab), std::end(vecTab), std::begin(vecTabMod),
               [](auto& v) { return v.data(); });
func(vecTabMod);
```

Comment: Should be needless to say, but each `vector` must remain alive for as long as a pointer to its `.data()` is used, since it owns that data and will deallocate it should it go out of scope.

Comment: @underscore_d Of course, because I want to use the data inside the vector, and modify them

Answer (score -2):

std::vector is worst choice for this soultion!
Using dynamic arrays is better.

Anyway you can use this code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int func(uint32_t firstDimensionSize, uint32_t* secoundDimensionSizes, int** tab){
    int sum = 0;
    for(uint32_t i = 0; i < firstDimensionSize; i++){
        for(uint32_t j = 0; j < secoundDimensionSizes[i]; j++){
            sum += tab[i][j];
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

int main(){
    std::vector<int> vecTab[6];
    vecTab[0].push_back(2);
    vecTab[0].push_back(5);
    vecTab[3].push_back(43);

    // Calculate count of elements in non dynamically arrays
    uint32_t firstDimensionSize = (sizeof(vecTab) / sizeof((vecTab)[0]));
    uint32_t* secoundDimensionSizes = new uint32_t[firstDimensionSize];
    int**tab = new int*[firstDimensionSize];
    for(uint32_t i = 0; i < firstDimensionSize; i++){
        secoundDimensionSizes[i] = vecTab[i].size();
        tab[i] = &(vecTab[i][0]);
    }

    std::cout << func(firstDimensionSize, secoundDimensionSizes, tab) << std::endl;
    delete[] secoundDimensionSizes;
    delete[] tab;
    system("pause");

}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. You don't need dynamic allocation here

Comment: Right, this shows how the data is kept in the vector and how we can get it more universally